# Lenovo ThinkPad L460, no boot options available

Tags: bios, thinkpad

I’ve ran into an issue with my ThinkPad L460. After installing Debian on the machine, the boot menu is completely blank and therefore I’m unable to boot into any OS or installation media. BIOS settings show Boot Options ATA HDD1, USB FDD and USB CD excluded from boot priority order and without a colon “:” at the end. If I re-enable these with ‘Shift+1’ and Save & Exit BIOS with F10, they get automatically disabled when I reboot.

I’m sure this is not an SSD failure or a faulty OS installation as I have removed and connected the drive to my desktop PC and it booted Debian just fine.

Secure Boot is disabled. I have tried every combination of UEFI/Legacy boot options without any luck. I have also tried removing CMOS battery and holding the power button for 30 seconds.

Lenovo Diagnostics and Diagnostic Splash Screen indicate that the laptop does recognize plugged-in USB drives.

I have a TL866 II Plus programmer with me in case flashing some chip on the motherboard would be a possible solution.

EDIT: As of now, Debian is the only OS on the SSD. I was trying to say that this laptop won't boot from USB either and that's why I'm screwed, because I can't boot into any tools. I've tried inserting USB drives with different installation media on them (these HAVE worked on this laptop before, so I know that there's nothing wrong with them) while trying every combination of boot option settings: Legacy only, UEFI only w/ CSM enabled, UEFI only w/ CSM disabled and Both.

Comment: Is Debian the only OS? If not [edit] your question to include that vital information

Comment: @Jonas First and foremost, **UEFI only** and **Secure Boot enabled or disabled is irrelevant** (for the type of live media you're trying. Second, that they *HAVE worked on this laptop before* doesn't mean they still do, corruption can happen and in fact it happens many times with live/installation media used improperly. Unless you tested them OK in another machine you should NOT assume they're fine.